# How to Calcualte inline control values in FormIO DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, formio

Do you know how to calcuate the inline values in the FormIO DataGrid by setting the "Calcuated Value" formula?

e.g. As shown in the attachment

[image]

I want to the get the sum of the values of both Number1 and Number2 and set to Number 3.

Thanks
// Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I found that there is a "row" paramter from the anonymous function of the calcualted value setting according to the offical website.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `row` parameter within your calculated value to determine this. The following would probably add a sum of the total within that row.

`value = parseInt(row.number1, 10) + parseInt(row.number2, 10);`

Comment: how can I sort and filter the Data Grid ? I am using the react redux app starter kit. kindly pls help.